# Is it possible to embed different compilers to my application?

Tags: java, c++, compiler-construction

I am trying to work on a desktop application using JavaFX/Java that requires me to compile and run c++ and Python code when it's requested, offline. I was wondering if this even possible?

How can this be done? Are there any libraries that can compile other languages' code and run them, which can be added in JavaFX/Java environment? Or do I need the user to install c++ compiler and Python in their machinees and then somehow integrate those tools in my application?

I would appreciate any help or insight.

Comment: Have you searched for Python or C interpreters / compilers implemented in Java?

Comment: @robinsax do you know any, which can be good for this purpose? Any reommendations?

Comment: This sounds somehow something like what Eclipse does. How does Eclipse solve it? (By calling external applications which are configured. -> [Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) for C/C++ Programming](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html)) Considering how frequently C++ compilers (like e.g. g++ and clang) are updated I wouldn't rely on a C++ compiler re-implementation in Java.

Comment: @Scheff what would you say is a good way to work on this? I would like to avoid the installation on the user's machines, if possible. Do you know any other way around this?

Comment: How critical is the C requirement? Maybe you can instead create a facility for providing user code in a less heavyweight language, e. g. Javascript? As for Python - what's your target platform?

Answer (score 0):

Packaging a C++ or python compiler into a Java application is impractical. Your system would have to store, unpack and install each compiler into the local directory, resulting in a massive file size, it would also take a very long time.

The best method is to require that the user have those compilers installed or provide them with the install utilities so they can install them separately.

Once the compilers are installed you can get Java to run a shell script which builds and compiles the files.

I hope that solved your question, if you need any further clarification please feel free to reach out to me.

Sincerely,
Owen